# Proof of Principle of the Iterated Suprema

Tags: real-analysis

I almost proved this expression, but at the end I have a problem with understanding. Can you explain me this, please? So we have:
Let be $X$ and $Y$ nonempty sets and let $h:X\times Y\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ have bounded range in $\mathbb R$. Let $F:X\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ and $G:Y\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $$F(x):=\sup\{h(x,y):y\in Y\},\quad G(y):=\sup\{h(x,y):x\in X\}.$$
To show that:$$\sup\{h(x,y):x\in X, y\in Y\}=\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}=\sup\{G(y):y\in Y\}$$
Proof: Let be $S:=\{h(x,y):x\in X, y\in y\}$, then we have $h(x,y)\leq F(x)\ \forall \ x \in X,y\in Y$. Then $\sup\{h(x,y):x\in X, y\in Y\}\leq F(x)\leq \sup\{F(x):x\in X\}$, so we have $$\sup\{h(x,y):x\in X, y\in Y\}\leq\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}.$$
Now let be $w<\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}$, then $\exists\ x_0 \in X$ with $w< F(x_0)=\sup\{h(x_0,y):y\in Y\}$, then $\exists \ y_0\in Y$ with $w< h(x_0,y_0)$. This implies that $w$ is not an upper bound for $S$, so $w<supS$. (I proved everything by myself until this place. I used the book from here.) Since this is true for any $w$ such that $w\leq\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}$, we conclude that $\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}\leq\sup S$. Combine these $2$
inequalities and we proved. My question is, why can we conclude that $\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}\leq\sup S$, since this is true for any $w$ such that $w<\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}$? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_i\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ for all $i\in\Delta$.

**Theorem: $\sup\,\bigcup_{i\in\Delta}T_i=\sup\,\{\sup T_i\;:\;i\in\Delta\}$.**

Proof:

For any fixed $j\in\Delta$, we have $\sup\,\bigcup_{i\in\Delta}T_i\geq \sup T_j$.

It immediately follows that $\sup\,\bigcup_{i\in\Delta}T_i\geq\sup\,\{\sup T_i\;:\;i\in\Delta\}$.

In the other direction, if $k\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that for all $i\in\Delta$ you have $k\geq\sup T_i$,

then for all $i\in\Delta$ and for all $t\in T_i$ you get $k\geq t$.

This means that $k\geq\sup\,\bigcup_{i\in\Delta}T_i$.

**Q.E.D.**

$\\$

Let $T_x=\{h(x,z)\;:\;z\in Y\}$. Clearly $\bigcup_{x\in X}T_x=S$.

Alternatively, let $T'_y=\{h(w,y)\;:\;w\in X\}$. Clearly $\bigcup_{y\in Y}T'_y=S$.

Apply the above theorem to these two cases.

Comment: Hello! Thank you!

Comment: @mathguruu edited with more details